# App that lets you individually control permissions on Android 5.1

Tags: gratis, android, security, privacy

I used to use an app on my (rooted/S-OFF, non-CM) phone that let me individually control each permission in a given app, much like is possible in Android 6.0. However, the app I used does not work on Android 5.1.

What other apps are there that offer this functionality?

Comment: It would help to know the name of the app that "used to work but no longer does". I've got no 5.1+ on any of my devices – but know several candidates which are "supposed to" work on 5.1 as well (having used/tried several of them). See e.g. my list of [Permission Manager](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_380) apps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy).

It is compatible with many versions of Android, including Android 5.1.  From the README:

> XPrivacy has been tested with Android version 4.0.3 - 5.1.1 (Ice Cream Sandwich, Jelly Bean, KitKat, Lollipop), and is reported to work with most Android variants, including stock ROMs.

It will allow you to control scores of different app permissions in [android](/questions/tagged/android), with great detail and specificity.

It is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) (free), but donations are accepted for the Pro version [here](http://www.xprivacy.eu/).

Both the free and Pro versions are [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source).

There is an extensive thread for XPrivacy on XDA-Developers [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=42488236).

XPrivacy requires the [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed) on a rooted Android device.

Here are two screenshots of XPrivacy to give you an idea of the power.  The first screenshot is of the basic interace.  The second is of the expert mode, which shows the fine-grained control that is possible with XPrivacy.

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]
<sup>*Xprivacy* (click images for larger variants)</sup>